# Symfony Paypal "Cannot use object of type RedirectResponse as array"

Tags: php, symfony, paypal

I have set up a simple express checkout Paypal, everything work just fine in Dev Mode but i have an error in production mode.

> Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse as array

```
$responseArray = $this->requestPaypal('SetExpressCheckout', array(
        'RETURNURL' => 'http://returnUrl.fr/member/payment/confirm/validate/membership/'.$ref,
        'CANCELURL' => 'http://cancelUrl.fr/member/payment/cancel',
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' =>  $info['price'],            # amount of transaction \
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',     # currency of transaction \
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => $info['description'],
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM' => $info['time'],
        ));

    $token = $responseArray['TOKEN']; // Error line

    $payPalUrl = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token='.$token.'';  

    return $this->redirect($payPalUrl);
```

METHOD RequestPaypal :

```
public function requestPaypal($method, $params)
{
    $params = array_merge($params, array(
        'METHOD' => $method,
        'VERSION' => $this->getParameter('version'),
        'USER' => $this->getParameter('username'),
        'SIGNATURE' => $this->getParameter('signature'),
        'PWD' => $this->getParameter('password'),
        ));

    $params = http_build_query($params);

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->getParameter('endpoint'),
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $responseArray = array();
    parse_str($response, $responseArray);

    if(curl_errno($curl))
    {
        $errors = curl_error($curl);
        $this->addFlash('danger', $errors);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('payment');
    }
    if($responseArray['ACK'] == 'Success')
    {
        curl_close($curl);
    }

    return $responseArray;
}
```

I think the code doesn't not work in prod because of paypal/sandbox.

Help Please

Nic

Comment: The code you posted does not contain the error triggering I think. Please add the `$this->requestPaypal()` method. Also in `$this->redirect()` a dollar sign is missing. Please post the code you run, not some edited stuff...

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you face with CURL error and your code executes this block of code: if(curl_errno($curl)) { ... }. I assume that method $this->redirectToRoute returns RedirectResponse object. After that, you trying to get "TOKEN" element on RedirectResponse object, which causes the error. To fix this issue, please add condition to check if method requestPaypal returns RedirectResponse object and return RedirectResponse from your controller to "payment" route with flash message, containing CURL error messages.

This code should handle this situation:

```
$responseArray = $this->requestPaypal('SetExpressCheckout', array(
        'RETURNURL' => 'http://returnUrl.fr/member/payment/confirm/validate/membership/'.$ref,
        'CANCELURL' => 'http://cancelUrl.fr/member/payment/cancel',
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' =>  $info['price'],            # amount of transaction \
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',     # currency of transaction \
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => $info['description'],
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM' => $info['time'],
        ));

    if ($responseArray instanceof RedirectResponse) {
        return $responseArray;
    }

    $token = $responseArray['TOKEN'];

    $payPalUrl = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token='.$token.'';  

    return $this->redirect($payPalUrl);
```

Comment: This error only happen when website on production with sandbox otherwise if live paypal everything work just fine

Comment: You should read CURL error messages to identify the cause. Maybe you have invalid credentials for sandbox Paypal account or sandbox is disabled.